# Reuse same table with new column

Tags: mysql, sql, datamodel

The table shown below is loaded from the database:[image]

When the user clicks Generate Grass Wedge it takes him or her to another page with this table:

[image]

Which is basically the previous table but with an extra editable field called "Enter grass weight". What i want to do is to append the grass weight values to the corresponding row and submit it to a new database table without altering the original table because the original will be reused. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this.

Comment: It entirely depends upon your database design. What if the same rows already exist in the new database table which these rows are to be inserted into with new values in the last column (weight)? If you happened to use an ORM of your interest, there would be something called "*Insert or Update*" (I do not fully get the question). But the question has basically nothing to with JSF/PrimeFaces. Perhaps, retagging or reformatting the question might make more sense.

Comment: Indeed, how to create the view depends on the model. Where exactly does grass weight end up in? In same entity? In other entity? How are they linked to each other? Etc.

Comment: @BalusC hi , my aim is to place the second table above into a new entity and table, the user can enter new grass values once a day and then store these values into a table in which they can be retrieved by date, in this new table a date value would be the primary key. Note the first table is static while the second table is the same except with dynamic grass values. Also thanks for your advice.